# QT Qvtkwidget. Interactorstyle change

Tags: c++, qt, vtk, qvtkwidget

My application is using qvtkwidget and I'm trying to change its interactorstyle.
With its default setting, holding down mouse wheel button moves objects, but I'd like it to be done by mouse right click. Does anyone know how to change it? Thanks.

Comment: You create your own interactor style class. I usually copy the source code and header for the most similar vtk interactor style that I need to change the behavior for. With this method I did not use vtkImageViewer I created the vtk render window ... myself.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create your own interactor like drescherjm commented.

There is a nice example on page http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Interaction/InteractorStyleUser